# Ruby range without left border in Array slicing

Tags: arrays, ruby, range

Today I found interesting way to slice array in Ruby:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
p a[...4] == a[0...4] # True
p a[...4] # [0,1,2,3]
```

Please explain how this works. `(...4) => (nil...4)`. But there is an error when write `(...4).to_a`: Cannot Iterate from NilClass.

Comment: Semantically, `nil` at any side of a range means without beginning/end. Hence why you can create such range (ex. range without beginning), you can slice with it (ex. index "without beginning" would imply "from the very start"), but you can't materialize it (ex. how do I generate all elements from "no beginning" til 4?). Implementationally, it's probably just hardcoded in Ruby's `Range` implementation.

Comment: A [beginless range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html#class-Range-label-Beginless+Ranges) _"[...] includes all values up to the end value"._ Without further context, "all values" is ambiguous. In the context of slicing an array however, that ambiguity is gone: `a[...4]` means _"slice all values up to (not including) element #4"_. It's equivalent to `a[0...4]` simply because an array starts at index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 2.6 introduced endless ranges:

```
# It's the same
2..
2..nil
Range.new(2, nil)
```

Ruby 2.7 introduced beginless ranges:

```
# It's the same
..2
nil..2
Range.new(nil, 2)
```

[`Array#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) with range returns a subarray specified by range of indices

Indices start with 0, therefore when use beginless range, it returns subarray from first element to specified one. Similarly for endless

At the same time you doesn't iterate through these ranges, you just take elements that match to the ranges

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

a[..2] # => [0, 1, 2]
a[2..] # => [2, 3, 4]
```

But when you try to convert beginless / endless range to array (or try to iterate through it), of course you get exception, because it's impossible to have array with infinite number of elements, array always have size

That's why `(2..).to_a` and `(..2).to_a` raise exception